# i want to get data from 7 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need help with the query which we get data from 7 tables. My task is: I have a drop-down with a list of crs so when I select a course I need to get a data in a combination of course, test and users.

output is like:

```
name| test 
--- |-----
sai | test
```

**table object_data:**

```
obj_id | type | title 
---    |------|------
3217   |crs   |it 
3221   |grp   |xyz 
3228   |tst   |test
```

table **object_reference**:

```
ref_id | obj_id 
---    |---------
337    |3217       
338    |3221      
343    |3228
```

table **tree**:

```
tree | child | parent 
---  |-------|------
1    |338    |337 
2    |343    |338
```

table **object_members**:

```
obj_id| usr_id 
---  |-------
3217 |3213
3221 |3213
```

table **usr_data**:

```
usr_id|name
---  |-------
3213|sai
```

table **tst_tests**:

```
test_id| obj_id
---  |-------
1    |3228
```

table **tst_tests**:

```
test_id| obj_id
---  |-------
122    |3228
```

table **tst_active**:

```
test_id| obj_id
---  |-------
122    |3213
```

The above tables have a combination of all data.crs and user combination in `obj_members` data and test and user combination in `tst_tests` and `tst_active` and test and course combination in `object_reference` and tree table.

Can anybody help me with a single query? I tried with three queries but I am not getting a result. below is my queries.

for user and course combination:

```
$users_query="SELECT o.title as course_title,u.*,u.usr_id,o.obj_id FROM object_data o,usr_data u,obj_members rn WHERE o.obj_id=rn.obj_id AND u.usr_id=rn.usr_id AND o.type='crs'  AND o.obj_id=$course";
```

for course and test combination:

```
$user_course_query ="SELECT  *,(select obj_id FROM `object_reference` obr WHERE obr.ref_id = c.child) as final_reference FROM object_data a JOIN object_reference b ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id JOIN tree c ON b.ref_id = c.parent JOIN object_reference d ON c.child = d.ref_id JOIN tree e ON d.ref_id = e.parent JOIN object_reference f ON e.child = f.ref_id JOIN object_data g ON f.obj_id = g.obj_id and a.obj_id=$course "
```

for user and test combination:

```
"SELECT u.firstname FROM usr_data u,object_data o,tst_active ta,tst_tests  WHERE u.usr_id=ta.user_fi AND tt.obj_fi=o.obj_id AND ta.test_fi=tt.test_id AND u.usr_id=$user->usr_id AND  o.obj_id = $course
```

Comment: Just do joins for each tables look here: [different joins](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join)

Comment: You have tst_tests listed twice with the same fields.  Why is that? Is that a mistake?   And tst_active has the same fields as tst_tests - couldn't they just be the same table?  Maybe the better question is can you change the table structure and design, or do you have to work with it as is?